# 31==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: negative-size-param: (size=-4) )

Tags: c++, vector

problem link : https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-students-unable-to-eat-lunch/

my solution :

```
int countStudents(vector<int>& students, vector<int>& sandwich) {

    int len = students.size();
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len+len; i++) {

        if (students[j] != sandwich[j]) {
            int front_student = students[0];
            students.erase(students.begin());
            students.push_back(front_student);
        }

        if (students[j] == sandwich[j]) {
            students.erase(students.begin());
            sandwich.erase(sandwich.begin());
        }

    }
    // int unable_to_eat = sandwich.size();
    return sandwich.size();
    
}
```

I tried to solve this problem and its work fine in my ide but whenever i try to submit my code, leetcode ide show me this error

```
=================================================================
==31==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: negative-size-param: (size=-4)
    #5 0x7f4819d390b2  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
0x602000000094 is located 4 bytes inside of 16-byte region [0x602000000090,0x6020000000a0)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #6 0x7f4819d390b2  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
==31==ABORTING
```

Comment: Why len+len is used? You get out of bounds access. Also students and sandwich sizes may be reduced during the loop.

Comment: You probably don't used the address sanitizer when you compile with the IDE. Compile with `-g -fsanitize=address` and you may get additional hints about the undefined behavior your program displays.

Answer (score 0):

You might access the vectors `students` or `sandwiches` even when they don't have any element in them. Take this case for example as input to your problem:

```
std::vector<int> stdudents {1, 0};
std::vector<int> sandwiches{1, 0};
```

As per the code, since the *top* of both vectors match, your code will keep removing all the elements of the vectors. Thus after 2 iterations, your `vector`s shall be empty. But the loop runs till `len + len` i.e. `2 + 2` or 4 iterations. So on the third iteration, when you go on to access `students[0]` (because `j` is always 0), you will be accessing invalid memory. If you replace `students[j]` with `students.at[j]`, you would actually hit an `std::out_of_range` exception.